# Closures over values vs context

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, closures, language-design

I'm thinking through various implementations of closures and am wondering about the merits of different styles.  It seems there are two choices, closing over the execution context or the values.  For instance, over the context we have:

```
a = 1
def f():
  return a
f() # returns 1
a = 2
f() # returns 2
```

Alternatively, we can close over values and have:

```
a = 1
def f():
  return a
f() # returns 1
a = 2
f() # returns 1
```

Are there languages that implement the second?  Are there advantages vs. disadvantages?

Comment: May be wrong (if so correct me) but second way is in the Javascript, without scoping (e.g. `...(variable)` at the end of block)

Comment: Well, one difference is that we seem to do really poorly at explaining the former in all languages that feature it, judging from the number of people expecting the latter. @om-nom-nom: I'm pretty sure JS does the former, otherwise get/set methods as closures wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case it's not a matter of context vs. value, but whether you close over a variable as a reference cell or the value that the variable contains.

If you really mean the context, you're referring to dynamic vs. lexical scope. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_scope#Lexical_versus_dynamic_scoping) Wikipedia article for an in-depth comparison.

Most languages implement lexical scope (or try to). Some languages do implement dynamic scope: notably older Lisps like ELisp for emacs. Most languages with closures (e.g., Scheme, Haskell, ML, and so on) close over the values in the lexical scope. Dynamic scope is often considered a bad idea because it's more difficult to reason about (it's "spooky action at a distance").

Note that even in lexically scoped languages, you can get behavior like your first example if you close over a reference cell. That's why Scheme and JavaScript closures behave like they do (because variables are reference cells).

Comment: Both are lexically scoped.  It's whether the closure is over variables or values.

Comment: You're right, the bit about "execution context" threw me off. I edited my post to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

C++ lambdas can capture explicitly by value:

```
int a = 1;
auto f1 = [a]() -> int { return a; }
f1() == 1;
a = 2;
f1() == 1;
```

Or by reference:

```
a = 1;
auto f2 = [&a]() -> int { return a; }
f2() == 1;
a = 2;
f2() == 2;
```

You can also implicitly capture either way:

```
auto f1 = [=]() -> int { return a; }
auto f2 = [&]() -> int { return a; }
```

The advantage is that you control which and whether variables are copied or referenced. A potential disadvantage is that you must beware of lifetime issues, because C++ references are non-owning: if `a` goes out of scope, then calling `f1` is still valid, but calling `f2` is undefined. If it’s natural and you don’t mind the overhead, you could always capture a `shared_ptr<T>` (pointer with shared ownership).

So for immutable values:

- Capturing by value forces a copy. Capturing by reference does not.
- Capturing by value has no ownership issues. Capturing by reference does.

For mutable values, you must of course capture by reference. Here’s a contrived example similar to `std::partial_sum()`:

```
int sum = 0;
auto f = [&sum](int i) -> int { sum += i; return sum; }

vector<int> input{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
vector<int> output;
transform(begin(input), end(input), back_inserter(output), f);

sum == 15;
output == vector{1, 3, 6, 10, 15};
```

Comment: Of course, capture by reference is a silliness in C++ since it would suffice to capture a pointer, not so?

Comment: @Yttrill: Not really. Lambdas can’t capture temporaries, so to capture `int x;` “by pointer” you’d need to say `int* y = &x;` then capture `y` by value. The lambda would need to dereference `y` explicitly, which is ugly, and has the same lifetime issues: `x` can still go out of scope. So I think references make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

In most languages with both closures and mutable variables, closures capture locations, not values (that is, the first behavior). Examples include Scheme, Python, and Javascript.

To do this safely, the language must, in many circumstances, heap-allocate mutable variables that are captured by closures. This is typically implemented by a compiler pass that converts variables that are actually mutated into explicitly-allocated mutable cells, after which the compiler can forget about the issue.

To avoid implicit heap-allocation, Java requires (required?) captured variables (by inner classes) to be declaredi `fnal` (ie, immutable). Other languages, like ML and Haskell, avoid the issue entirely because variables are always immutable. In C++ capture-by-reference can be unsafe, as Jon points out in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Closures should behave as in the first case, but some languages provide the 2nd case.

Smalltalk works according to the first case. Let's assume a class defines methods *m* and *test*:

```
m
| counter c |  "temporary vars"
counter = 0.
c = [ counter = counter + 1. counter ]. 
^ c. "returns the closure"

test
| c | "temporary vars"
c = self m. "obtain a closure that increments a counter"
c value. "return 1"
c value. " returns 2"
```

To think about closure, you must think about the stack. If closure *c* is defined in method *m* and closes over the temporary variable *counter*, the stack frame of *m* can not be removed until the closure is garbage collected. Closure are first-class, so you don't know when there will be no reference to it anylonger.

But many closures do no close over any temporary variable, or close over temporary variables that are not modified after the closure is defined. In the latter case, the value of the temporary variable at the moment the closure is defined can be copied into the closure, so that they don't need a reference to the stack frame of *m*.

In the case of the closure *c* above, the closure can copy the value of *counter*. This what Java mandates by forcing tempory variables that are closed over to be final.

If method *m* was

```
m
| counter c |  "temporary vars"
counter = 0.
c = [ counter = counter + 1. counter ].
counter = 1. 
^ c. "returns the closure"
```

I guess it would defeat the optimization, because *counter* is mutated after the creation of the closure.

That's how I understand closures at least.

Comment: I think you are missing the point because the question glosses over the fundamental distinction a bit. The question is reframed as to whether the value at the time of closure formation or closure execution should be used -- in the OP's post, these are the same for both cases of f(). The OP's question actually asks the wrong question: whether the value at the time of definition is used, as opposed to closure formation and execution. Clearly this is nonsense in a language that doesn't execute function definitions, but merely declares them.

Comment: @Ytrill Right, it's not very focused to the question, but maybe still interesting to the OP. I guess there are three kinds of closures: (1) those that copy value at time of creation (no real closure) (2) those that close over with lexical scope (the common case) (3) those that close over with dynamic scope (hard to reason about)

Answer (score 1):

Felix actually provides quite a complex semantics which is sometimes counter-intuitive. Closures capture the context via a pointer to the context's frame .. at the point closures are formed. Therefore you would expect that the captured variable always reflect the current value of the variable at the time the closure is executed.

This is not the case, because the optimiser may replace the variable with its value, in particular, if the "variable" is declared like:

```
val x = 1;
```

it is taken as an immutable value, and such a substitution is deemed safe. This is true even if the value is passed as an argument! For example:

```
fun f(x:int) () => x;
val y = 1;
val fy = f y;  // closure formed
println$ fy();
```

It's likely we have fy defined as if:

```
val fy = fun () => 1;
```

had been written. In this case it may be the same for a variable:

```
var z = 1;
val fz = f z;
z = 2;
println$ fz (); // prints 1 .. maybe
```

by replacing the x with the value of z at the time of closure formation BUT it could also print 2, by replacing the x with the variable name z instead.

In Felix, it is **not determinate** which optimisation is applied and that is deliberate: it allows the compiler the freedom to choose (what it thinks is) the best optimisation.

If you want to force an interpretation you can: for the parameter argument:

fun f(var x:int) () => x; // forces eager evaluation, copies argument to parameter
   fun f( x: unit -> int ) => x(); // forces lazy evaluation

And for the original question: you can force the lazy interpretation by simply using a pointer:

```
var x = 1;
fun f()=> *&x;
```

It is nonsense to force the eager interpretation. If you want that you do this:

```
var x = 1;
val y = x;
var x = 2;
fun f() => y; // prints 1
```

I must say I am NOT HAPPY with these semantics, but that's what happens at the moment, and it seems quite logical. What is more troubling is this:

```
var g : unit -> int;

for var i = 0 upto 10 do
   val x = i;
   fun f()() => x;
   if i == 3 do
     g = f();
   done
done
```

The for loop is flat, no stack frame. Here 'x' is a value, but it isn't immutable!
If you can predict the value printed by g() you're doing better than me (and I designed the language :)

Unfortunately the optimisations obtained by these semantics are mandatory: we do not want to end up with the performance of, er, well, Haskell (no offense intended).

The moral of the story is: *if your code depends on the answer to the OP's question, on your head be it! Write code where the semantics are determinate if you require that*.

Answer (score 1):

Various languages have it in one of those two ways, or both.

The main distinction is what happens when you assign to the variable. Thus, as others have pointed out, in languages where variables are immutable

In languages that capture by value, one issue is how to deal with assignments to that variable. Since it's captured by value

- As others have pointed out, many languages without explicit syntax for dealing with capturing by value vs. reference capture by reference, including: Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Scheme, Perl, Go, Smalltalk, etc.
- As others have pointed out, ML languages (SML, OCaml) and Haskell can be said to capture by value, because their variables are immutable, so there is no real difference between the two, and capture by value is simpler
- As others have pointed out, Java requires captured variables to be `final`, essentially for the purpose of capturing by value, because otherwise there would be confusion at having two separate mutable copies of a variable in the same scope; but when they are `final`, they can't be modified so there is no difference between having one copy and many copies
- C++11 lets you choose whether to capture by value, or by reference. You list the variables to capture in brackets. Variables with `&` are by reference; otherwise, it's by value. `=` by itself captures all unlisted variables by value; `&` by itself captures all unlisted variables by reference. One has to be careful when capturing variables by reference, to not capture variables that go out of scope. Interestingly (unlike Java), it is possible to capture a variable by value, but have it be *mutable*, by using the `mutable` modifier on the anonymous function.
- PHP, likewise, lets you choose when you declared variables to capture. `&` indicates capture by reference; otherwise by value.
- Blocks in Apple's development tools (for languages C, C++, and Objective-C; available in Mac OS X 10.6+ and iOS 4+) also allow you to choose. When you first create a block, it has access to captured variables by reference; however, such a block is not allowed to leave the scope (e.g. be returned) if it captures local variables since they will go out of scope. One must copy a block in order to have it leave the scope; captured variables are captured by value when the block is copied. It is also possible to indicate that a local variable is to be captured by reference by blocks when copied, by using the `__block` modifier when declaring that variable. This probably allocates it on the heap.